# Bug with iOS render of display: flex?

Tags: ios, css, html, flexbox

I'm using HTML5 display and summary elements.  I'm using a custom marker as a ::before pseudo element.  The summary element can contain up to 2 span elements.

I've applied a display: flex (or display: inline-flex) rule to the summary element.

FF and chrome render the summary element exactly as expected - a single line and I have control of the width of the pseudo and span elements with flex.

But when viewed on my iPad or iPhone the summary element gets rendered as if it were a block or flex-direction: column.  The pseudo element and each span gets rendered onto a new line.

I have very similar code applied to divs with the same span elements but with an empty pseudo element.  iOS renders as expected in this instance (flex-direction: row).

I'm not clear what's causing this behaviour and it's difficult for me to debug because I've not got an iOS device with which to develop.

```
<details>
 <summary>
  <span>content</span>
  <span>content</span>
 </summary>
</details>
```

SCSS

I'm using mixins with all the vendor prefixes. I'll not clutter this up with those!

```
details {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 &[open] > summary::before {
  content: '\e313';
 }
}

summary {
 display: flex; //or could be inline-flex
 flex-direction: row; //not strictly needed since this is the default
 &::before {
  content: '\315';
  flex: 0 0 $MARGIN;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
}
```

The following renders correctly in iOS

```
div {
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: row; 
 &::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 0 $MARGIN;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
}
```

Output
FF & chrome (renders details/summary as a row)

marker  content  content

iOS (renders details/summary as a column)

marker

content

content

Answer (score 1):

I decided to work around the problem rather than continue to see if there is a solution.  Instead of using display: flex on the summary element I've switched to display: inline-block on the spans.

There is detection of iOS using

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {}
```

And I've had to use a number of media queries to ensure sensible render given that I cannot rely on flex.  The inline-block span elements have to have their widths calculated ahead of time.

Lastly, flex remains on the divs (these mirror the summary elements but don't have any daughters).

If I get a more satisfactory solution I'll update here.